# Text filling on scroll effect with useScroll and useTransform

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, framer-motion

I am trying to create an effect in react that when a page is scrolled my text is filled gradually from top to bottom with color like this:

I think that useTransform variable doesn't work with being inside the styling text.

[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAoOP.png)

In order to do that I use 2 same texts - one white with just the outline and the other filled with color that is being revealed with clip-path style. To track scroll I use framer-motion and useScroll as well as useTranslate. It works well when assigned to style right, but not when the value needs to be a longer text like clipPath.

```
    const {scrollY} = useScroll();
    const y = useTransform(scrollY, [0,500], [0,100] );

    const style = {
       clipPath: `polygon(0px 0px, 100% 0px, 100% ${y}%, 0px ${y}%)`,
       right: x,
    };
```

the outcome of that is just fully filled text no matter the scroll.
here are the divs:

```
<div style={{right: x}} className="textbox2">
   <motion.h2 style={{marginRight: x}} id="name">MAKS</motion.h2>
   <motion.h2 style={style} id="overname">MAKS</motion.h2>
</div>
```

I am still new to react so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`y` is an object.
Try to `console.log("y", y)` and you'll see by yourself.

The value you want to access here is `y.current`:

```
const style = {
       clipPath: `polygon(0px 0px, 100% 0px, 100% ${y.current}%, 0px ${y.current}%)`,
       right: x,
    };
```

Please let me know if this was useful